# Form options Component

Tags: aem

Im new to aem. I am using the form options core components.

The form options - List  is not picking up the static list which is created .

Any suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: At first: Please specify wich AEM version do you use. You can doing it by clicking on the edit link underneath your question. Second: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please share AEM version, a piece of code or any exceptions in the browser or in the logs that you are getting in order to help you. Thanks.